# How do I identify which user logged into my app via firebase auth?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, spring-boot, nosql, crud

This is an architectural design question.

I'm working on a React application that has a Spring boot (CRUD) backend, and I've recently added a Firebase Auth set-up for logging in and out. So far, users can log in/log out and then update a TODO list and save to a H2 database.

The issue is that I don't know how to relate user logins via firebase, to the DB updates. For example, a user logs in and updates the TODO list, when they hit save, I want to store their updated data in a DB table. I don't know how to relate the saved information to that user so that they get the correct TODO list information the next time they log in. I obviously want to avoid the situation where a user sees everyone else's data.

To do this should I store their UID from firebase? I want to avoid storing email addresses.

The application is a CRUD model. If there's a good way to implement what I currently have with firebase auth, then great. But if not, I'm willing to rip out the CRUD backend and use a firebase No/SQL DB instead.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to associate database information with a Firebase Authentication is indeed to store the UID of that user with the information.

If the write happens from you own backend code, ensure that the user can only associate data with their own UID by following this process:

1. [Get the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) from the user in the client-side application code.
2. Pass that ID token to your server-side code over a secure connection.
3. [Decode and verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) on the server.
4. Use the UID from the decoded token in the data, and ensure the user is authorized to perform the operation.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).